Как открыть из своего Android приложения приложение Яндекс Навигатор с заданными пунктами назначения?
Как открыть приложение Яндекс карты из своего Android приложения ,где будут передаваться точное место прибытие без координат.(ну или подскажите как находить эти координаты)

https://yandex.ru/dev/yandex-apps-launch/maps/doc/concepts/yandexmaps-android-app.html
